# How to change the default link time of pymysql

Tags: python, pandas, pymysql

In my project, I used pandas and pymysql to read the database. The default setting is that pymysql will automatically disconnect after 8 hours if you do not perform any operation after creating a link.

I used close () to close the link, but the database shows that the link exists and has not been operated for more than 80000 seconds

python 3.10.5

I tried to close it with close(), but it didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

I gauss you can try to change "wait_timeout" in mysql system setting which default is 28800s

Comment: Because it is a production environment, our leader is cautious about changing the database, so this method can only be considered at last. Thank you

Comment: connection.ping(reconnect=True)  ？

Comment: I wonder if it can automatically disconnect itself after accessing the database

Answer (score 0):

To set the timeout for pymysql read and write operations, use the following parameters that can be passed to `pymysql.connections.Connection(..)` when you establish the connection:

`read_timeout` – The timeout for reading from the connection in seconds (default: None - no timeout)
Similarly, you have:
`write_timeout` – The timeout for writing to the connection in seconds (default: None - no timeout)